# Please help me to solve the following differential equation of order 3 for v(t) function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve the following differential equation of order 3 for v(t) function

$-225v^{'''}(t)+259t^{2}v^{''}(t)+(-35t^4+518t)v^{'}(t)+(t^{6}-70t^{3}+130)v(t)=0$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions (other than 0) don't seem to be expressible in closed form: at least, Maple can't find closed-form solutions.

There are series solutions with coefficients $a_n$ satisfying the recurrence:
$$ a_n + (-175 - 35 n) a_{n + 3} + (259 n^2 + 3367 n + 11008) a_{n + 6} + (-225 n^3 - 5400 n^2 - 42975 n - 113400) a_{n + 9} = 0 $$

Comment: Thank you very much. How to get explicit form of this recurrence for a_{n}?

Comment: How to get the recurrence, or how to get an explicit formula for $a_n$?  I doubt that the latter exists.

Comment: does Maple have a better time if you tell it to run time backwards, maybe shrink indices so it is $b_{n+3} , b_{n+2}, b_{n+1}, b_n$ standing in  for $a_n, a_{n+3}, a_{n+6}, a_{n+9} \; \; ? \; \;$

Comment: I have no idea how running time backwards could possibly help here.  Shrinking indices gives you the recurrence
$b_{{n}}+ \left( -175-105\,n \right) b_{{n+1}}+ \left( 2331\,{n}^{2}+
10101\,n+11008 \right) b_{{n+2}}+ \left( -6075\,{n}^{3}-48600\,{n}^{2}
-128925\,n-113400 \right) b_{{n+3}} = 0
$.  Maple can't solve the recurrence (but it's rarely able to solve a recurrence with nonconstant coefficients), and it's not able to guess a generating function for it.

Comment: I asked a friend  how to write $c_{n+1} = (n^2 + 1) c_n$ in some sort of special functions. I can do $b_{n+1} = (kn + m) b_n$ using ratios of the Gamma function, I guess the denominator is $\Gamma(\frac{m}{k}).$ This may or may not lead anywhere

Comment: @WillJagy $c_{n+1} = (n^2+1) c_n$ has solutions $c_n = \text{const}\; \Gamma(n-i) \Gamma(n+i)$.  Three-term or four-term recurrences (that can't be reduced to two-term) are another matter entirely.

Comment: Dmitry found me this: https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~petkovsek/PetZakPreprint.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy If I'm using Maple's LREtools package correctly, there are no nontrivial polynomial, rational, hypergeometric or dAlembertian solutions in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Robert.